# webpage / html as wallpaper

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, html, wallpaper

I tried [komorebi](https://github.com/cheesecakeufo/komorebi) which has this feature, but it **changes the right click menu**. I need something like [lively wallpapers](https://github.com/rocksdanister/lively), which I use on windows, which doesnt change anything other than wallpaper, I'm using Linux mint cinnamon,

Had seen [HTML Wallpaper](https://store.kde.org/p/1324580/) on store.kde.org, I believe it only works on kde.

---

Is there any package which does this without changing anything else other than wallpaper?